# How to get data from multidimensional array by omitting one column?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am storing info in an array in a loop like that:

```
while ($ind = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $array["uniqueName"][$ind][$hash]["mac"] = $mac;
```

How can I get all $mac's if I am not given $hash, so by all hashes in context:

```
$array["uniqueName"][432][?]["mac"]
```

What can I do with '?' above? Can I omit that somehow?

Comment: First of all: What would you expect the final array to look like?

Comment: A list of $mac's. It does not even need to be an array. I just need to display all the $mac's stored in by $id, not given $hash

Comment: `foreach($array["uniqueName"][$id] as $hash=>$comp){if(isset($comp["mac"]))}` like this?

Comment: When I tried Jeroen's answer with the combination of yours, it worked! Like. I changed this line:
foreach($array["uniqueName"][$ind] as $hash=>$x){ 

I don't know why, because i dont use $x afterwards, but $hash now actually contains values. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can loop over the hash keys like this:

```
$macs = array();
foreach($array["uniqueName"][$ind] as $hash){
    array_push($macs, $hash["mac"]);
}
```

Update from comment:

The foreach statement loads every key $array["uniqueName"][$id] contains into the $hash variable, one by one. So you don't have to know what these keys actually are (or even if there are any), you can just use them by referring to them using the $hash var. So in effect, that foreach statement loops over all keys $array["uniqueName"][$id] contains.

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer

Comment: Can I have problems with this, because I have few arrays (actually $GLOBALS[][][] .. ) like this: 
$array["uniqueName"][$ind][$hash] = $opSt;
$array["uniqueName"][$ind][$hash]["mac"] = $mac;
$array["uniqueName"][$ind][$hash]["name"] = $name; ?

Comment: I'm don't expect problems, you just loop over the keys and extract the 'mac' value, doesn't matter if there are other values there.

Comment: I actually get no values for $hash with "as" in my program.

Comment: I noticed a typo in the code, I fixed in your original code but not in my answer (only just now). It uses $id instead of $ind. Is that the problem?

Comment: $id is the right thing there. My sql query looks like this: SELECT id,hash,mac,name,value from data;

Comment: The purpose of this is that I want to be able to get all those things within just one array throughout all the context, regarding whether hash and id and ['name'] or  whatever the ending column is.

Comment: Wouldn't `$hash` in your way be **value** instead of **key** [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)? If you want to use `$hash` that way, I think you should use `foreach($array['uniqueName'][$id] as $hash=>$info)`.

Comment: @user1524316 if 'id' is just a query result column name you have to use it like this: $array["uniqueName"]["id"][$hash]. Executing the query doesn't create a 'magical' var $id

Comment: Yes! That's what I just did, and it works! Thank you very much, both of you